# Phone number formatting an EditText in Android

Tags: android

I am making a simple Address Book app (targeting 4.2) that takes name, address, city, state, zip and phone.

I want to format the phone number input as a phone number (XXX) XXX-XXXX, but I need to pull the value out as a string so I can store it in my database when I save. How can i do this??
I have the EditText set for "phone number" input but that obviously doesn't do too much.

Comment: Do you need the string to be of all numbers, or do you want the spaces, dashes and parentheses also?

Comment: I guess the string could be formatted the same as the phone number, just as long as I can put it into a string variable and then insert it into my database table

Comment: you can use pattern matching with regular expression

Comment: You should also remember that (xxx) xxx - xxxx is only the number format in the US and a few other places.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is a library called [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) that can help you to cope with phone number conversions and comparisons. For instance, use ...

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(text.getText().toString())
```

... to format your number in a standard format.

```
PhoneNumberUtils.compare(String a, String b);
```

... helps with fuzzy comparisons. There are lots more. Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html for more.

p.s. setting the the EditText to `phone` is already a good choice; eventually it might be helpful to add `digits` e.g. in your layout it looks as ...

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextId"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:digits="0123456789+" 
/>
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. I use that library and haven't had a bad time yet.

Comment: Just be careful to test it on different versions of Android...it tends to work differently on the newer APIs.

Comment: @ *JaVAndroid*: yes, definitely; and it's sometimes tricky 'cause different countries allow different characters too.

Comment: PhoneNumberUtils is the class behind PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher, so we have the same basic answer. The difference is your approach is a one-off occurrence while the TextWatcher constantly updates. (+1 for you.) But why are you using an input type _and_ digits?

Comment: I was allowed to enter symbols like `N`, `*` and others into my phone number fields, if I didn't use `digits`. In fact, these characters can be part of a phone number, so they are actually allowed. If you only want to allow numbers, use `digits` for further restriction.

Comment: Hmm, what if the user wants to save / dial an extension after the main number?  By taking away these special characters you've prevented any "advanced" numbers, you also disregard regions that use `.` instead of `-`.  I personally feel if a user dumps an `N` or `;` in their number without knowing what it means, it's their fault. :)

Comment: @Sam: no matter, the way Android allows entering phone numbers is fully correct and there might be no need to change this - unless your product owner has other requirements ... ;-)

Comment: @André What if I want to format the EditText as the number is being entered?? That way formats it perfectly for how its stored in the DB, but when the user types in "123" i want it to come up as (123) and then (123)XXX-XXXX for the other 7 numbers

Comment: In fact, I think it's good to have both, a canonical format and a user format in your database table. I'd use Sams approach or `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber()` for the canonical format, 'cause it simplifies phone number comparison a lot. In addition, I'd store the number as the user entered it, 'cause he's used to look up the number as he entered it. If you are looking at a very particular format Raghunandans solution (using pattern matching) might be perfect.

Comment: How to do it for TextView?

Comment: Is there any way to remove the formatting from text while calling getText() ?

Comment: hello any one get solution for this please share proper answer

Answer (score 113):

Simply use the [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html), just call:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

---

**Addition**
To be clear, PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher's [backbone](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java#PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29) is the PhoneNumberUtils class. The difference is the TextWatcher maintains the EditText while you must call `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber()` every time you change its contents.

Comment: i was tried like this but its not set text as format of (XXX) XXX-XXXX . its allow format like xxx-xxx-xxxx

Comment: it works only for full number text, but if you entered only half of phone number you get nothing

Answer (score 33):

Simply Use This :

In Java Code :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

In XML Code :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumber"
    android:inputType="phone"/>
```

This code work for me. It'll auto format when text changed in edit text.

Comment: And use `String phoneNumbers = maskedString.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");` to get phonenum without any spaces

Comment: Take care with android:inputType="phone" as some phones like Xiomi do not show keyboard with numbers. When user tries to type some letter (cause number keyboard is not shown to her/him) , user does not get feedback. This is really strange. So, for the best practice, I will recommend android:inputType="number"

Comment: Hey you can use `android:inputType="phone|number"` as a fallback mechanism

Comment: It is not working for Japanese phone numbers. If you try to put the ISO code ("JP") it does not format the number at all.

Comment: inputType="phone" apparently doesn't exist, is this just for me?

Comment: Not Working in api 23

Comment: it only works for full number text

Answer (score 22):

I've recently done a similar formatting like 1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX for Android EditText. Please find the code below. Just use the TextWatcher sub-class as the text changed listener :
....

```
UsPhoneNumberFormatter addLineNumberFormatter = new UsPhoneNumberFormatter(
            new WeakReference<EditText>(mYourEditText));
    mYourEditText.addTextChangedListener(addLineNumberFormatter);
```

...

```
private class UsPhoneNumberFormatter implements TextWatcher {
    //This TextWatcher sub-class formats entered numbers as 1 (123) 456-7890
    private boolean mFormatting; // this is a flag which prevents the
                                    // stack(onTextChanged)
    private boolean clearFlag;
    private int mLastStartLocation;
    private String mLastBeforeText;
    private WeakReference<EditText> mWeakEditText;

    public UsPhoneNumberFormatter(WeakReference<EditText> weakEditText) {
        this.mWeakEditText = weakEditText;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        if (after == 0 && s.toString().equals("1 ")) {
            clearFlag = true;
        }
        mLastStartLocation = start;
        mLastBeforeText = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO: Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Make sure to ignore calls to afterTextChanged caused by the work
        // done below
        if (!mFormatting) {
            mFormatting = true;
            int curPos = mLastStartLocation;
            String beforeValue = mLastBeforeText;
            String currentValue = s.toString();
            String formattedValue = formatUsNumber(s);
            if (currentValue.length() > beforeValue.length()) {
                int setCusorPos = formattedValue.length()
                        - (beforeValue.length() - curPos);
                mWeakEditText.get().setSelection(setCusorPos < 0 ? 0 : setCusorPos);
            } else {
                int setCusorPos = formattedValue.length()
                        - (currentValue.length() - curPos);
                if(setCusorPos > 0 && !Character.isDigit(formattedValue.charAt(setCusorPos -1))){
                    setCusorPos--;
                }
                mWeakEditText.get().setSelection(setCusorPos < 0 ? 0 : setCusorPos);
            }
            mFormatting = false;
        }
    }

    private String formatUsNumber(Editable text) {
        StringBuilder formattedString = new StringBuilder();
        // Remove everything except digits
        int p = 0;
        while (p < text.length()) {
            char ch = text.charAt(p);
            if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                text.delete(p, p + 1);
            } else {
                p++;
            }
        }
        // Now only digits are remaining
        String allDigitString = text.toString();

        int totalDigitCount = allDigitString.length();

        if (totalDigitCount == 0
                || (totalDigitCount > 10 && !allDigitString.startsWith("1"))
                || totalDigitCount > 11) {
            // May be the total length of input length is greater than the
            // expected value so we'll remove all formatting
            text.clear();
            text.append(allDigitString);
            return allDigitString;
        }
        int alreadyPlacedDigitCount = 0;
        // Only '1' is remaining and user pressed backspace and so we clear
        // the edit text.
        if (allDigitString.equals("1") && clearFlag) {
            text.clear();
            clearFlag = false;
            return "";
        }
        if (allDigitString.startsWith("1")) {
            formattedString.append("1 ");
            alreadyPlacedDigitCount++;
        }
        // The first 3 numbers beyond '1' must be enclosed in brackets "()"
        if (totalDigitCount - alreadyPlacedDigitCount > 3) {
            formattedString.append("("
                    + allDigitString.substring(alreadyPlacedDigitCount,
                            alreadyPlacedDigitCount + 3) + ") ");
            alreadyPlacedDigitCount += 3;
        }
        // There must be a '-' inserted after the next 3 numbers
        if (totalDigitCount - alreadyPlacedDigitCount > 3) {
            formattedString.append(allDigitString.substring(
                    alreadyPlacedDigitCount, alreadyPlacedDigitCount + 3)
                    + "-");
            alreadyPlacedDigitCount += 3;
        }
        // All the required formatting is done so we'll just copy the
        // remaining digits.
        if (totalDigitCount > alreadyPlacedDigitCount) {
            formattedString.append(allDigitString
                    .substring(alreadyPlacedDigitCount));
        }

        text.clear();
        text.append(formattedString.toString());
        return formattedString.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: @samik i am getting this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (2 ... 2) ends beyond length 1

Comment: Modded Version of the private class to limit total possible input digits see-> https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/e254a215c54aa4be0400a3511a23f730 @Rao's had the same problem try using my NoExtraDigits modifications...

Answer (score 18):

Maybe below sample project helps you;

https://github.com/reinaldoarrosi/MaskedEditText

That project contains a view class call `MaskedEditText`. As first, **you should add it in your project**.

Then you add below xml part in res/values/attrs.xml file of project;

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MaskedEditText">
        <attr name="mask" format="string" />
        <attr name="placeholder" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then you will be ready to use `MaskedEditText` view.

As last, you should add MaskedEditText in your xml file what you want like below;

```
<packagename.currentfolder.MaskedEditText
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/maskedEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="5"
    app:mask="(999) 999-9999"
    app:placeholder="_" >
```

Of course that, you can use it programmatically.

After those steps, adding `MaskedEditText` will appear like below;

[image]

As programmatically, if you want to take it's text value as unmasked, you may use below row;

```
maskedEditText.getText(true);
```

To take masked value, you may send `false` value instead of `true` value in the `getText` method.

Comment: UPDATE: eh, this library doesn't apply inputType=phone|number (at least in styles.xml) to edittext. So I chose https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText - works good

Answer (score 15):

You need to create a class:

```
public class PhoneTextFormatter implements TextWatcher {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private EditText mEditText;

    private String mPattern;

    public PhoneTextFormatter(EditText editText, String pattern) {
        mEditText = editText;
        mPattern = pattern;
        //set max length of string
        int maxLength = pattern.length();
        mEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        StringBuilder phone = new StringBuilder(s);

        Log.d(TAG, "join");

        if (count > 0 && !isValid(phone.toString())) {
            for (int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s", phone));
                char c = mPattern.charAt(i);

                if ((c != '#') && (c != phone.charAt(i))) {
                    phone.insert(i, c);
                }
            }

            mEditText.setText(phone);
            mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    private boolean isValid(String phone)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++) {
            char c = mPattern.charAt(i);

            if (c == '#') continue;

            if (c != phone.charAt(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Use this as follows:

```
phone = view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
phone.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneTextFormatter(phone, "+7 (###) ###-####"));
```

Comment: This solution is more generic as the user can add a format. Now I haven't yet tested it.

Comment: Thanks! I'd also recommend `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE); setText("+7 ("); setSelection(4)`

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. This is solution that leaves room to manipulate how the data should the formated.

Answer (score 7):

If you're only interested in international numbers and you'd like to be able to show the flag of the country that matches the country code in the input, I wrote a small library for that:

https://github.com/tfcporciuncula/phonemoji

Here's how it looks:

[image: library demo]

Comment: this is spectacular!

Answer (score 4):

Follow the instructions in this Answer to format the EditText mask.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34907607/1013929

And after that, you can catch the original numbers from the masked string with:

```
String phoneNumbers = maskedString.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

More like clean:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

String text = etyEditText.getText();
    int textlength = etyEditText.getText().length();

    if (text.endsWith("(") ||text.endsWith(")")|| text.endsWith(" ") || text.endsWith("-")  )
                return;

    switch (textlength){
        case 1:
            etyEditText.setEditText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "(").toString());
            etyEditText.setSelection(etyEditText.getText().length());
            break;
        case 5:
            etyEditText.setEditText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, ")").toString());
            etyEditText.setSelection(etyEditText.getText().length());
            break;
        case 6:
            etyEditText.setEditText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, " ").toString());
            etyEditText.setSelection(etyEditText.getText().length());
            break;
        case 10:
            etyEditText.setEditText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "-").toString());
            etyEditText.setSelection(etyEditText.getText().length());
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful who wants to format number as per U.S. standard

Answer (score 3):

```
//(123) 456 7890  formate set

private int textlength = 0;

public class MyPhoneTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


        String text = etMobile.getText().toString();
        textlength = etMobile.getText().length();

        if (text.endsWith(" "))
            return;

        if (textlength == 1) {
            if (!text.contains("(")) {
                etMobile.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "(").toString());
                etMobile.setSelection(etMobile.getText().length());
            }

        } else if (textlength == 5) {

            if (!text.contains(")")) {
                etMobile.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, ")").toString());
                etMobile.setSelection(etMobile.getText().length());
            }

        } else if (textlength == 6 || textlength == 10) {
            etMobile.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, " ").toString());
            etMobile.setSelection(etMobile.getText().length());
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful, could you please explain how this answers the OP question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use spawns to format phone numbers in Android. This solution is better than the others because it does not change input text. Formatting remains purely visual.

```
implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.4'
```

Formatter class:

```
open class PhoneNumberFormatter : TransformationMethod {
private val mFormatter: AsYouTypeFormatter = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getAsYouTypeFormatter(Locale.getDefault().country)

override fun getTransformation(source: CharSequence, view: View): CharSequence {
    val formatted = format(source)
    if (source is Spannable) {
        setSpans(source, formatted)
        return source
    }
    return formatted
}
override fun onFocusChanged(view: View?, sourceText: CharSequence?, focused: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) = Unit

private fun setSpans(spannable: Spannable, formatted: CharSequence): CharSequence {

    spannable.clearSpawns()

    var charterIndex = 0
    var formattedIndex = 0
    var spawn = ""
    val spawns: List<String> = spannable
        .map {
            spawn = ""
            charterIndex = formatted.indexOf(it, formattedIndex)
            if (charterIndex != -1){
                spawn = formatted.substring(formattedIndex, charterIndex-1)
                formattedIndex = charterIndex+1
            }
            spawn
        }

    spawns.forEachIndexed { index, sequence ->
        spannable.setSpan(CharterSpan(sequence), index, index + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }

    return formatted
}

private fun Spannable.clearSpawns() =
    this
        .getSpans(0, this.length, CharterSpan::class.java)
        .forEach { this.removeSpan(it) }

private fun format(spannable: CharSequence): String {
    mFormatter.clear()
    var formated = ""
    for (i in 0 until spannable.length) {
        formated = mFormatter.inputDigit(spannable[i])
    }
    return formated
}

private inner class CharterSpan(private val charters: String) : ReplacementSpan() {

    var space = 0

    override fun getSize(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?): Int {
        space = Math.round(paint.measureText(charters, 0, charters.length))
        return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end)) + space
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, x: Float, top: Int, y: Int, bottom: Int, paint: Paint) {
        space = Math.round(paint.measureText(charters, 0, charters.length))
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x + space, y.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawText(charters, x, y.toFloat(), paint)
    }
    }

}
```

Uasge:

```
editText.transformationMethod = formatter
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Regular Expression with pattern matching to extract number from a string.

```
    String s="";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("(1111)123-456-789"); //editText.getText().toString()                                      
    while (m.find()) {
    s=s+m.group(0);
    }
    System.out.println("............"+s);    

    Output : ............1111123456789
```

Comment: Certainly a solution... I still think PhoneNumberUtils is the way to go in most cases though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. I have make a most of better solution for you. You can see this simple app link below.

```
private EditText mPasswordField;
public int textLength = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
    mPasswordField.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    String text = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
    textLength = mPasswordField.getText().length();

    if (text.endsWith("-") || text.endsWith(" ") || text.endsWith(" "))
        return;

    if (textLength == 1) {
        if (!text.contains("(")) {
            mPasswordField.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "(").toString());
            mPasswordField.setSelection(mPasswordField.getText().length());
        }

    } else if (textLength == 5) {

        if (!text.contains(")")) {
            mPasswordField.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, ")").toString());
            mPasswordField.setSelection(mPasswordField.getText().length());
        }

    } else if (textLength == 6) {
            mPasswordField.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, " ").toString());
            mPasswordField.setSelection(mPasswordField.getText().length());

    } else if (textLength == 10) {
        if (!text.contains("-")) {
            mPasswordField.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "-").toString());
            mPasswordField.setSelection(mPasswordField.getText().length());
        }
    } else if (textLength == 15) {
        if (text.contains("-")) {
            mPasswordField.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "-").toString());
            mPasswordField.setSelection(mPasswordField.getText().length());
        }
    }else if (textLength == 18) {
        if (text.contains("-")) {
            mPasswordField.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "-").toString());
            mPasswordField.setSelection(mPasswordField.getText().length());
        }
    } else if (textLength == 20) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }



}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
```

Not: Don't forget "implement TextWatcher" with your activity class.

Link :https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-yo9VvU7jyBMjJpT29xc2k5bnc

Hope you are feeling cool for this solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accept only numbers and phone number type using java code

```
 EditText number1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edittext); 
    number1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
     number1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789”));
      number1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(14)}); // 14 is max digits
```

This code will avoid lot of validations after reading input

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me for (216) 555-5555

```
etphonenumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                String text = etphonenumber.getText().toString();
                int  textLength = etphonenumber.getText().length();
                if (text.endsWith("-") || text.endsWith(" ") || text.endsWith(" "))
                    return;
                if (textLength == 1) {
                    if (!text.contains("("))
                    {
                        etphonenumber.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "(").toString());
                        etphonenumber.setSelection(etphonenumber.getText().length());
                    }
                }
                else if (textLength == 5)
                {
                    if (!text.contains(")"))
                    {
                        etphonenumber.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, ")").toString());
                        etphonenumber.setSelection(etphonenumber.getText().length());
                    }
                }
                else if (textLength == 6)
                {
                    etphonenumber.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, " ").toString());
                    etphonenumber.setSelection(etphonenumber.getText().length());
                }
                else if (textLength == 10)
                {
                    if (!text.contains("-"))
                    {
                        etphonenumber.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length() - 1, "-").toString());
                        etphonenumber.setSelection(etphonenumber.getText().length());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```