# format edittext input price format

Tags: android

When we work with the currency    we need to use  ',' separator in appropriate places  .  For example 1500 as 1,500.
I have a issue. My applications require formatting the EditText's value while typing. I.E., a number that needs to be formatted with decimal and thousands separators. Example, I input 123456789, the EditText display 123.456.789.

How to I do this issue ? Thank all.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647327/phone-number-formatting-an-edittext-in-android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better way to Format Currency Input editText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext)