# Espresso Soft Keyboard Type

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, android-espresso

Using Espresso can we validate which type of Soft Keyboard appears when we select a particular input field. For Example let we select Mobile Number - EditText it must display numeric keyboard. Can we validate it with Espresso?

Comment: why would you like to check with espresso what kind of keyboard you use? To make sure you have number keyboard decalre it in EditText vars as it is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647327/phone-number-formatting-an-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Espresso` just run on `Single application.` All view must belong to current `activity`. Since `Keyboard` is belong to `System`, `Espresso` is unable to check it. You could use it `uiautomator` inside your `Espresso` test case!
I don't try it yet but I think it could be help.