# Android phone number formatting is not working with type pad and EditText

Tags: android, formatting, number-formatting

Please see the google drive link below. It's a very simple app for the USA Phone number formatting.

Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-yo9VvU7jyBeS01ek9VSXpYRzg

Comment: didn't get your problem

Comment: `Please see the google drive link `, no, you have to post the problem here.

Comment: find the solution     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647327/phone-number-formatting-an-edittext-in-android

Comment: Brother "Nilesh Rathod" Actually you are right. But there was something wrong. If you see it cheerfully, you can see there first type of character is alloys display and if i type another character first character is alloys display and it's the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have make a solution myself for my problem. Actually i get this solution idea from "Kailash Barochiya" Via "Rajasekhar" . I have dedicated my solution for another who have this problem fetching.

Thanks "Kailash Barochiya" And "Rajasekhar"

Solution Link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-yo9VvU7jyBMjJpT29xc2k5bnc