# How to format Phone Number from PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher through local?

Tags: android, locale, android-textwatcher

I am using Phone Number Formatting TextWatcher to format number according to given locale. my App support multiple language and i want to format phone number according to user selection like Uber app is doing for login. but Phone Number Formatting TextWatcher is not working when i am using its constructor with locale.
below is the code snippet:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("ar"));
```

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647327/phone-number-formatting-an-edittext-in-android