# Phone number format in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, phone-number

In my application, I have a editText which will accept phone number from the user, My target is, as soon as user enters the phone number it should be formatted (Like by applying on text changed listener) , format is like `XXX-XXX-XXXX`.

I wrote the code as

```
ePhone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            private Pattern pattern;
            private Matcher matcher;
            String a;


            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                boolean flag = true;            
                if (flag) {

                    if (((ePhone.getText().length() + 1) % 4) == 0) 
                    {
                        if (ePhone.getText().toString().split("-").length <= 2) 
                        {
                            ePhone.setText(ePhone.getText() + "-");
                            ePhone.setSelection(ePhone.getText().length());
                        }
                    }
                    a = ePhone.getText().toString();
                } else {
                    ePhone.setText(a);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stus

            }
        });
```

But when the user wants to delete a number from this `editText`, its not working properly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in that edit text corner put a close button if user click that button clear everything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supposing that you wanna format the phone number as per US format.

```
+1 (###) ###-####,1 (###) ###-####,###-####,###-###-####,011 $
```

The following will serve your purpose:

```
phoneEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    private boolean mFormatting; // a flag that prevents stack overflows.
    private int mAfter;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
    }

    //called before the text is changed...
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        mAfter = after; // flag to detect backspace.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // Make sure to ignore calls to afterTextChanged caused by the work done below
        if (!mFormatting) {
            mFormatting = true;
            // using US formatting.
            if(mAfter != 0) // in case back space ain't clicked.
                PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(
                    s,PhoneNumberUtils.getFormatTypeForLocale(Locale.US));
            mFormatting = false;
        }
    }
});
```

If you need location specific services, i.e. for each location, you need specific format of that place (refer to [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html)).
If you need only the format you needed, then write a custom function in the place of line in the above code snippet.

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(
    s, PhoneNumberUtils.getFormatTypeForLocale(Locale.US));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works in both case delete and edit.

```
 public class PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
EditText Edt;
int keyDel=0;
public PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(EditText edt){
 Edt =edt;
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    Edt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                keyDel = 1;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (keyDel == 0) {
        int len = Edt.getText().length();
        String input=Edt.getText().toString();
        if(len == 4) {
            Edt.setText( input.substring(0,3)+"-"+ input.substring(3) );
            Edt.setSelection(Edt.getText().length());
        }
        if(len == 8) {
            Edt.setText( input.substring(0,7)+"-"+ input.substring(7) );
            Edt.setSelection(Edt.getText().length());
        }
    } else if(keyDel==1){
        int len = Edt.getText().length();
        if(len == 4||len==8) {
            Edt.setText(Edt.getText().delete(Edt.getText().length()-1,Edt.getText().length()) );
            Edt.setSelection(Edt.getText().length());
        }
        keyDel = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use foolowing code it will work.

```
String number="5129892680";
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(number);
```