# How to align text in TextInputLayout in android?

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, material-components

In a `RelativeLayout` I have a `TextInputLayout` where I have `EditText` inside it to type phone number and a `Textview` inside a `LinearLayout` where I am showing the country code.
When we start typing `TextInputLayout slide to top, but I want it to slide to as in image 3.

I am facing issue in this can somebody help me?
This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                >
        
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/error_mobile_no"
                                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/error_mobile_no"
                                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/error_mobile_no"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">
        
                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/country_code_textview"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/lorin_regular"
                                        android:text="+971"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                                </LinearLayout>
        
                                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/error_mobile_no"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                                    app:errorEnabled="true">
        
                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumberDetailedActivity"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                                        android:autofillHints=""
                                        android:paddingStart="35dp"
                                        android:backgroundTint="#6283a3"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/lorin_regular"
                                        android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
                                        android:inputType="phone"
                                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                                        android:textColorHint="#6283a3" android:textSize="14sp" />
                                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
```

This is an image of the field before entering text.[image]

This is the image after entering text.[image]

But I am trying to get it to look like this.
[image]

Comment: Answer by @GabrieleMariotti would definitely help, just change the theme as you want and set [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674114/8244632) for the formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **`app:prefixText`** to display the prefix:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:hint="mobile_number"
        app:prefixText="+971"
        ...>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:inputType="phone"
            .../>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]